# How can I make a sound play and stop after 1 second in javascript?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a pomodoro clock in React and one of the requirements is to play an alarm when the clock reaches 0.  I want the sound to play for 1 second and created this function to make it happen.

```
const playAlarm = () =>{
    beep.current.play();

    setTimeout(()=>{
      beep.current.pause();
      beep.current.currentTime = 0;
    }, 1000);

}
```

I'm calling it inside of a `useEffect()` hook like this.

```
useEffect(()=>{

    if(countState){
      interval = setInterval(()=>setCurrentTime(currentTime - 1000), 1000);
      
      if(currentTime === 0){
        playAlarm();
        clearInterval(interval);
        handleTimerType();
      }
    }
    else{ clearInterval(interval); }

    return ()=> clearInterval(interval);

}, [countState, currentTime]);
```

When my timer reaches 0 the sound only plays for a millisecond or so and shuts off.  Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-o8pk5t?file=src/components/timer/timer.jsx) of the project.

Comment: can you share where `beep` comes from? is it a library? also please add a reproducible example

Comment: What's the logic behind `currentTime` condition? You also want to defined `let interval;` inside `useEffect` so it doesn't leak outside. What's `handleTimerType`? As the comment above says provide a code sample.

Comment: I added the stackblitz so you can see how everything is set up.

Comment: That is one second.... try setting it to two seconds if it's too short?

Comment: It sound good in my end.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work, but if you run the tests you'll see that one fails, which says the sound doesn't play at all.